# How to convert string like '001100' to numpy.array([0,0,1,1,0,0]) quickly?

Tags: python, numpy, types, format, type-conversion

I have a string consists of 0 and 1, like `'00101'`. And I want to convert it to numpy array `numpy.array([0,0,1,0,1]`.

I am using `for` loop like:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.zeros((1,5),int)
S = '00101'
for i in xrange(5):
    X[0][i] = int(S[i])
```

But since I have many strings and the length of each string is 1024, this way is very slow. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

map should be a bit faster than a list comp:

```
import  numpy as np

arr = np.array(map(int,'00101'))
```

Some timings show it is on a string of 1024 chars:

```
In [12]: timeit np.array([int(c) for c in s])
1000 loops, best of 3: 422 µs per loop

In [13]: timeit np.array(map(int,s))
1000 loops, best of 3: 389 µs per loop
```

Just calling list in s and using dtype=int is faster:

```
In [20]: timeit np.array(list(s), dtype=int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 329 µs per loop
```

Using [fromiter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html)  and passing `dtype=int` is faster again:

```
In [21]: timeit  np.fromiter(s,dtype=int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 289 µs per loop
```

Borrowing from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262022/2141635), using fromstring and uint8 as the dtype is the fastest:

```
In [54]: timeit  np.fromstring(s, 'int8') - 48
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.54 µs per loop
```

Even rebinding the name and changing the dtype is still by far the fastest:

```
In [71]: %%timeit
   ....: arr = np.fromstring(s, 'int8') - 48
   ....: arr = arr.astype(int)
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.23 µs per loop
```

Even considerably faster than Ashwini's join:

```
In [76]: timeit  np.fromstring(' '.join(s), sep=' ', dtype=int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.6 µs per loop
```

As @Unutbu commented out,`np.fromstring(s, 'int8') - 48`  is not limited to ones and zeros but will work for all strings composed of ASCII digits.

Answer (score 2):

I think list comprehension would be faster than your normal for loop method -

```
import numpy as np

s = '00101'

np.array([int(c) for c in s])
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Timeit comparison to your method (with a string of 1024 length) -

```
In [41]: S = '0' * 512 + '1' * 512

In [43]: %%timeit
   ....: X = np.zeros((1,len(S)),int)
   ....: for i in range(len(S)):
   ....:     X[0][i] = int(S[i])
   ....:
1000 loops, best of 3: 854 µs per loop

In [45]: %%timeit
   ....: Y = np.array([int(c) for c in S]).reshape((1,len(S)))
   ....:
1000 loops, best of 3: 339 µs per loop
```

I did the reshape, just so that both arrays are same shape, but I do not think you really need the reshaping , with the list comprehension the shape of array you get is `(<length of string> ,)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
>>> s = '00101'
>>> np.fromstring(' '.join(s), sep=' ', dtype=int)
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])

>>> s = '00101' * 1000
>>> %timeit np.fromiter(s, dtype=int)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.fromstring(' '.join(s), sep=' ', dtype=int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 499 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using fromstring method?

```
np.fromstring('1, 2', dtype=int, sep=',')
```

More details [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)

Answer (score 0):

`np.array(map(lambda x: int(x), s))`

Comment: what is the `lambda` for? Just use `int`